# Remotely access SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

My client is using a hotel management software that uses Microsoft SQL server for database and now I need to extract their database for further doing work on it. Can I use connection string to remotely access my clients database?

Comment: Yes.  You can use a connection string to access a database.  Did you try?  Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a connection string.

If you want a little help trying to build a working connection string here's a little trick! Create a text file somewhere on your local drive, rename the extension of the file from .txt to .udl this makes it a Universal Data Link file. Double click on the file and go through the Microsoft wizard to and when you get the details correct click OK to close it.

Finally right click on the file and select to 'Open With' and choose Notepad... then there you go... that will give you your connection string.